# Applying apply tactic to premises instead of the goal

Tags: coq

If the goal state is like this:

```
  a : Prop
  b : Prop
  H1 : a
  H2 : b -> c
  ============================
   c
```

Then I can convert it to the following state using `apply H2` tactic:

```
  a : Prop
  b : Prop
  H1 : a
  H2 : b -> c
  ============================
   b
```

Now, I want to do the same but for hypothesis:

```
  a : Prop
  b : Prop
  H1 : a
  H2 : b -> a
  ============================
   b
```

I want to introduce a new hypothesis(or simplify the existing hypothesis) such that I have a new `H3 : b` in premises. Is that possible ?

I tried various variations of `apply` but everything is leading to some kind of error. Code for bringing up to the above state:

```
Lemma test : forall {a b : Prop},
    a /\ (b -> a) -> b.
Proof.
  intros a b.
  intros [H1 H2].
Abort.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible, because your `test` lemma does not hold.  For instance, take `a` to be `True` and `b` to be `False`.  Both premises (`a` and `b -> a`) hold, yet `b` does not hold.

This would work, however, if you changed the statement of your result a little:

```
Lemma test : forall a b : Prop, a /\ (a -> b) -> b.
Proof. intros [H1 H2]. apply H2 in H1. exact H1. Qed.
```